# Rails 4 Not Running Server

Tags: ruby, server, startup

When running the command

```
rails server
```

instead of the server running, I am getting the following output:

[image]

Why is the server not running?

Comment: figured it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722950/rails-server-command-not-working-in-terminal

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not executing `rails server` inside a rails app directory.
Use `rails new app_name` and change directory into that app and run `rails server` again.